# Compute the parameters of the linear code $C=\{(f(x_1),...,f(x_n))| f(x)\in F_k[x]\}$ where $F_k[x]$ is the space of polynomials of $deg(f(x)) \leq k$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, combinations, coding-theory

F is finite field with cardinality q and $F_k[x]=\{f(x)\in F[x] | deg(f(x)) \leq k \}$. We choose $x_1,...,x_n$ elements of F different from each other and for $k \leq n$ we consider a code $C=\{(f(x_1),...,f(x_n)) | f(x) \in F_k[x]\}$.
Show that C is linear code and compute parameters.

Is it true that this code has generetor matrix the (nxk) matrix

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^{k-1}\\
1 &x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots & x_2^{k-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^{k-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it's right. Take the information vector $c=(c_0,\ldots,c_{k-1})$ or equivalently the polynomial $f(x) = c_0 + c_1x + \ldots + c_{k-1}x^{k-1}$.
Then the encoding gives
$$(c_0,\ldots,c_{k-1}) \cdot \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & \ldots,& 1\\
x_1 & x_2 & \ldots & x_n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
x_1^{k-1} & x_2^{k-1} & \ldots & x_n^{k-1}
\end{array}\right)\\
= \left(
\sum_i c_ix_1^i,
\sum_i c_ix_2^i,
\ldots,
\sum_i c_ix_n^i\right)
= (
f(x_1), f(x_2), \ldots ,f(x_n)).
$$
All vectors are row vectors and the generator matrix is a $k\times n$ matrix here.

Comment: +1 You might want to add that the code is called a $[n,k+1]$ _nonsystematic_ Reed-Solomon code. Indeed, the formulation in this question is the original formulation of Reed-Solomon codes by Reed and Solomon in their seminal paper in 1960. The now much more commonly used cyclic version of Reed-Solomon codes came later.